# How do I properly reload a UITableView after reordering or deleting a row?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView whose cells also display their row number. Obviously, after reordering or deleting a row I have to also update potentially all row number labels.

I guess, there must be a better way to achieve this without interfering with the associated animations for deleting a row than

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self.tableView performSelector:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.6];
}
```

and for reordering a row

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)sourceIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)destinationIndexPath
{
    ...
    [self.tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
}
```

must it not?

Comment: what you really want to do..? do you want to reload your data...?

Comment: I update the the model objects to reflect their correct new position inside the list. Therefore, reloading the data for the table view propagates these updates to the UI.

Comment: Did you try wrap your updating/deleting in:    [self.tableview beginUpdates];
    [self.tableview endUpdates];

Comment: @mvadim In the scenario I am talking about I am interactively moving/deleting a row with Apple UITableView standard behavior (like -[UITableView setEditing:animated:]). Apple takes care of moving/deleting the row appropriately. I wouldn't know what to wrap with beginUpdates/endUpdates.

Comment: [self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:... inSection:...]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
[self.tableView endUpdates];